# How to search for a part of a word with ElasticSearch indices

Tags: php, elasticsearch, lucene

I've recently started using ElasticSearch and I can't seem to make it search for a part of a word.

Example: I have three documents from my couchdb indexed in ElasticSearch:

```
{
 "_id" : "1",
 "name" : "John Doeman",
 "function" : "Janitor"
}
{
 "_id" : "2",
 "name" : "Jane Doewoman",
 "function" : "Teacher"
}
{
 "_id" : "3",
 "name" : "Jimmy Jackal",
 "function" : "Student"
}
```

So now, I want to search for all documents containing "Doe"

```
curl http://localhost:9200/my_idx/my_type/_search?q=Doe
```

That doesn't return any hits. But if I search for

```
curl http://localhost:9200/my_idx/my_type/_search?q=Doeman
```

It does return one document (John Doeman).

Am trying with this url `http://localhost/el/index.php?str=*doe*`.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();

$params = array();
$params['index'] = 's3';
$params['type'] = 's3files';
$params['body']['query']['match']['content'] = $_GET['str'];

$result = $client->search($params);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

How can I make ElasticSearch find both John Doeman and Jane Doewoman when I search for "Doe" ?

Comment: `curl http://localhost:9200/my_idx/my_type/_search?q=Doe*`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search for a part of a word with ElasticSearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467067/how-to-search-for-a-part-of-a-word-with-elasticsearch)

Comment: @apex-meme-lord Yes working fine but am using php code to search, it not showing correct result

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217833/elasticsearch-match-substring-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply try using a wildcard first:

```
curl http://localhost:9200/my_idx/my_type/_search?q=Doe*
```

If that's enough, you can get away with that. Otherwise, there are other more advanced solutions by creating custom analyzers with edge ngram [tokenizers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) and [filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html).

Comment: Yes working fine but am using php code to search, it not showing correct result.

Comment: Your PHP code uses a `match` query which is different from what the `q=` query does (i.e. it is a `query_string` query). Try this PHP code: `$params['body']['query']['query_string']['query'] = $_GET['str'];`

Comment: One more doubt, @val `Array ( [index] => s3 [type] => s3files [id] => 1679 [body] => Array ( [filename] => Services.docx [content]=>test [user_id]=>35))` i want to search content and user_id in the query string. how can i do?

Comment: How can i pass the $param?

Comment: In order to search for the `content` field, you can do it like this: `$params['body']['query']['query_string']['query'] = 'content:' . $_GET['str'];` You can check the details of the query syntax [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this,**Wildcard Query** Matches documents that have fields matching a wildcard expression (not analyzed).

```
      curl http://localhost:9200/my_idx/my_type/_search
      {"query":
        {
       "wildcard" : { "name" : "doe*"  }
         }
      }
```