# If the number of letters is low, why doesn't elasticsearch work?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, autocomplete, elasticsearch-query

```
$params = [
            'from' => $from,
            'size' => config('app.pagination'),
            'index' => $index,
            //'type' => $this->type,
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'filter' => [
                            'term' => $where
                        ],
                        'must' => [
                            'multi_match' => [
                                'query' => $match,
                                'fields'=>$fields,
                                'fuzziness' => "AUTO:1,5",
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

Hello, I don't have a problem with my query above.

For example, I am looking for a **pizza**. I am writing **pizaz** again.
*These queries return the correct records to me.*

But I have a problem.
It doesn't return anything when you type **piz**.

How can I solve this problem? I want it to work when I write it missing.

Comment: does this answer your question: [Elasticsearch match substring in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217833/elasticsearch-match-substring-in-php)

Comment: So how do I add this wildcard query to my values. How should 'must' and 'should' work.

Comment: @SpartanTroy, you should use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html in this , let me know if you need a sample index and query in JSON format as I am not aware of php syntax

Answer (score 0):

Add **minimum_should_match**  parameter to your query.

Using **minimum_should_match** sets a threshold (absolute number, percentage, or combination of these) for matching clauses in boolean queries.

As you know from [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

> If the bool query includes at least one should clause and no must or
>   filter clauses, the default value is 1. Otherwise, the default value
>   is 0.